# When the output stream is being closed in the servlets,does it mean the socket connection is being closed as well?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Recently , I have decided to start creating own servlets container to get the better understanding of how do apache tomcat and server application generally work.So,to do that,I need to study socket programming.
So , as far as I know when the output stream of a socket is being closed that the socket connection is being closed as well.I can't understand how to make the apache tomcat not close the socket connection after a http request/response interaction to optimize my application.

Here is the code snippet :

```
Socket socket;
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
pw.close();
```

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

So, if the another socket try to get something from input stream then it will get a exception that the socket is closed.I have just given the naked sockets with no an application protocol(HTTP,WS...)

But , what's going on when there is a servlet and its outputstream is being closed by a programmer like this :

```
// The http request has the header - Keep-alive : true   

public class DisplayHeader extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
   response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.close();

}
```

As far as I'm concerned the closing of any high stream will call close() method other streams staying lower until the base stream to close.So, having closed the printwriter the outputstream of a socket has been closed as well.So,might the decision be just flush the buffer content and that's it and don't use the close method until it become needed?

Comment: Closing the servlet output stream releases the connection to the container's connection pool. You must close it.

Comment: @user207421 , actually , I don't want the connection will be released,I want one to go living on.I mean socket connection should not be closed after a response will be sent.It's assumed that there will a lot of request in the future from the same client and I don't want the socket connection being opened every time.

Comment: @user207421 , one question ,please.Was the apache tomcat built on the Package com.sun.net.httpserver?

Comment: You *do* want it to be released, to the connection pool. I didn't say anything about it being closed. This is how it implenents HTTP 1.1 keepalive. Tomcat is not built on that package.